# How do we show $\int_{[0,\:1)^2}\exp\left(-\frac{\left\|x-\frac{x_i+x_j}2\right\|^2}{\sigma^2}\right)\:{\rm d}x=\pi\sigma^2$ here?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, exponential-function, error-function

Let $D=[0,\sqrt N)^d$ for some $N\in\mathbb N$, $x_i,x_j\in D$ and $\sigma>0$. In equation $(30)$ of [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3450626.3459880#page=11) I've read that, if $d=2$, then \begin{equation}\begin{split}\int_D\exp\left(-\frac{\left\|x-\frac{x_i+x_j}2\right\|^2}{\sigma^2}\right)\:{\rm d}x&=\int_{\mathbb R^2}\exp\left(-\frac{\left\|x-\frac{x_i+x_j}2\right\|^2}{2\left(\sigma/\sqrt 2\right)^2}\right)\:{\rm d}x\\&=2\pi\frac{\sigma^2}2=\pi\sigma^2\end{split}\tag1\end{equation} as long as $\sigma\ll\sqrt N$ or "assuming an infinite periodic set".

How can we show this? I actually don't understand what's meant by "assuming an infinite periodic set". But even when $\sigma\ll\sqrt N$, I don't understand how we obtain the claim (at least **approximately**).

### **EDIT**

So, okay. Let us write $z:=\frac{x_i+x_j}2$. We've then got $$\int_{\left[0,\:\sqrt N\right)^d}\exp\left(-\frac{\|x-z\|^2}{\sigma^2}\right)=\sqrt N^d\int_{[0,\:1)^d}\exp\left(-\frac N{\sigma^2}\left\|x-\frac z{\sqrt N}\right\|^2\right)\:{\rm d}x\tag2.$$ Now note that $$\sqrt N\int_0^1\exp\left(-\frac N{\sigma^2}\left(x-\frac{z_i}{\sqrt N}\right)^2\right)\:{\rm d}x=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\sigma\left(\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{z_i}\sigma\right)-\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{z_i}\sigma-\frac{\sqrt N}\sigma\right)\right).\tag3$$ Now how does $\sigma\ll\sqrt N$ imply $(3)$ is equal to $\pi\sigma^2$? I guess we need to use $\frac{\sqrt N}\sigma\to\infty$ instead of $\sigma\ll\sqrt N$, but I still don't see how to deal with $\frac{z_i}\sigma$ in $(3)$ when I take this limit ...

### **EDIT 2**

Maybe we need to assume $\sigma=\delta\sqrt N$ and consider $\delta\to0+$ as suggested by [FShrike](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/815585/fshrike) in the comments. For this, note that $$\int_0^{\sqrt N}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-z_i)^2}{\sigma^2}\right)\:{\rm d}x=\sigma\int_{-\frac{z_i}{\sqrt N}\frac1\delta}^{\left(1-\frac{z_i}{\sqrt N}\right)\frac1\delta}e^{-x^2}\:{\rm d}x\tag3.$$ Now the integral on the right-hand side clearly tends to $\sqrt\pi$ as $\delta\to0+$. I guess this is why they say that $(3)$ is approximately equal to $\sqrt\pi\sigma$. However, since $\sigma\to0+$ as $\delta\to0+$, this is somehow strange.

### So, that's why I would like to figure out the ofllowing: How small must $\delta$ actually be to make the error between $\sqrt\pi\sigma$ and $(3)$ smaller than a given $\varepsilon>0$; i.e. $$0<\sqrt\pi\sigma-\int_0^{\sqrt N}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-z_i)^2}{\sigma^2}\right)\:{\rm d}x<\varepsilon\tag4?$$

Comment: The condition $\sigma \ll \sqrt{N}$ is used to justify replacing the domain of integration with all $R^2$, more or less.

Comment: @Aruralreader Yes, sure. But why is that possible then? And instead of replacing the integration domain, can't we argue with the error function?

Comment: This is a purely heuristic calculation such as one might find in a physics paper. If we work with  "$P$" being infinitely spread out i.e. $D=\Bbb R^2$ literally or if we work with $\sigma\ll\sqrt{N}$ then one can **approximately** write: $$\int_D\cdots=\int_{\Bbb R^2}\cdots=\pi\sigma^2$$

Comment: That is all there is to it. They have made an estimation (not a question of precise mathematics and $\operatorname{erf}$ and all that jazz), and have not claimed any particular degree of precision of this estimate (which *would* have been a suitable question of precise mathematics). In particular, the equality signs are not genuine equality signs

Comment: @FShrike Thank you for your comment. I already guessed that they understand their equation as actually an "approximate equality", but if it is really a sensible approximation, shouldn't we be able to give a suitable assumption on $\sigma$ and $\sqrt N$ (such as $\sigma\ll\sqrt N$) to show that this is indeed a sensible approximation using $(3)$?

Comment: It’s sensible because the error is what you get if you integrated  on the complement of $D$ (well, the complement $D\cup -D$) where every element has square magnitude $>N$ and if we divide by $\sigma^2\ll N$ we still get a reasonably large value: $\exp(-\text{large})=\text{small}$ so the error is small

Comment: @FShrike Okay, we need to write $$\int_0^{\sqrt N}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-z_i)^2}{\sigma^2}\right)\:{\rm d}x=\int_{-\infty}^\infty-\int_{-\infty}^0-\int_{\sqrt N}^\infty.$$ The first integral is equal to $\sqrt\pi\sigma$. How exactly do you show that the other two are small?

Comment: @FShrike The second integral can be transformed into $$\int_{-\infty}^{-z_i}e^{-\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2}}\:{\rm d}x.$$ here inside the integral $|x|^2\ge|z_i|^2$, but not $|x|^2\ge N$, as you've claimed. So, it seems like I'm missing something.

Comment: @FShrike Or is the problem that we need to consider $D$ as a toroidal domain?

Comment: We don’t really need to show anything. Again it’s just heuristic. Notice the integrand is even, I find it likely that they intended to integrate over $(-\sqrt{N},\sqrt{N})^d$ (up to a doubling constant of $2$. Outside of that domain the integrand is just small. Leave it at that, this is not precise. You could maybe establish rigorous estimates given $\sigma:=\delta\sqrt{N}$ for small enough $\delta$, but for the purposes of this paper you probably don’t have to

Comment: @FShrike The latter seems to be a good idea (see my latest edit). Can we show that the error is negligible (or even vanishes) as $\delta\to0+$?

Comment: Well $$\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\int_{-z_iN^{-1/2}\delta^{-1}}^{(1-z_iN^{-1/2})\delta^{-1}}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$By definition of improper integral. So the limit would equal the claimed Gaussian value. An estimate for the rate of convergence can be given but again, it’s likely not worth it for the sake of the paper

Comment: @FShrike I'm not interested in the particular paper. I want to make this rigorous. So, if you could give an answer - including convergence rate - that would be great.

Comment: @FShrike Please see my latest edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$Take $z$ to be in $(0,\sqrt{N})^2$ and $0<\sigma$. By the multivariate integral substitution rule we have: $$\int_{[0,\sqrt{N})^2}\exp(-\sigma^{-2}\|x-z\|^2)\d\lambda(x)\\=\sigma^2\int_{[-z_1/\sigma,(\sqrt{N}-z_1)/\sigma)\times[-z_2/\sigma,(\sqrt{N}-z_2)/\sigma)}\exp(-\|x\|^2)\d\lambda(x)$$

The difference between this and: $$\sigma^2\int_{\Bbb R^2}\exp(-\|x\|^2)\d\lambda(x)=\pi\sigma^2$$Is exactly: $$\psi(\sigma,N,z):=\sigma^2\int_{\Bbb R^2\setminus[-z_1/\sigma,(\sqrt{N}-z_1)/\sigma)\times[-z_2/\sigma,(\sqrt{N}-z_2)/\sigma)}\exp(-\|x\|^2)\d\lambda(x)$$We can bound: $$\begin{align}0&<\psi(\sigma,N,z)\\&\le\sigma^2\int_{\{|u|\ge\mu/\sigma\}\times\{|v|\ge\nu/\sigma\}}\exp(-\|(u,v)\|^2)\d\lambda(u,v)\\&\le4\sigma^2\int_{(\kappa/\sigma,\infty)^2}\exp(-\|(u,v)\|^2)\d\lambda(u,v)\end{align}$$Where $0<\mu:=\min(z_1,\sqrt{N}-z_1),\,0<\nu:=\min(z_2,\sqrt{N}-z_2)$ and $\kappa:=\min(\mu,\nu)>0$. We can continue to bound: $$\begin{align}\psi(\sigma,N,z)&\le4\sigma^2\exp(-2\kappa^2/\sigma^2)\int_{(\kappa/\sigma,\infty)^2}\exp(-(u^2-\kappa^2/\sigma^2+v^2-\kappa^2/\sigma^2))\d\lambda(u,v)\\&=4\sigma^2\exp(-2\kappa^2/\sigma^2)\left(\int_{\kappa/\sigma}^\infty\exp(-(x^2-\kappa^2/\sigma^2))\d x\right)^2\end{align}$$

If we substitute $y^2=x^2-\kappa^2/\sigma^2$ then $0\le\frac{\d x}{\d y}=\frac{y}{x}=\sqrt{1-\frac{\kappa^2}{\sigma^2x^2}}\le1$ so I can continue to bound: $$0<\psi(\sigma,N,z)\le4\sigma^2\exp(-2\kappa^2/\sigma^2)\left(\int_0^\infty\exp(-y^2)\d y\right)^2=\pi\sigma^2\cdot\exp(-2\kappa^2/\sigma^2)$$

Now - if $z$ is "pretty close" to the middle of the region, say we've fixed a constant $0<\alpha<1$ and $\alpha\sqrt{N}\le\min(z_1,z_2,\sqrt{N}-z_1,\sqrt{N}-z_2)$ and if $\sigma:=\delta\sqrt{N}$ for some defined $\delta>0$ then you've got: $$0<\left|\pi\sigma^2-\int_D\cdots\right|\le\pi\sigma^2\cdot\exp(-2\alpha^2/\delta^2)$$If $\delta\ll\alpha$ the right hand side is extremely small indeed. What's more, we're actually saying the right hand side is small *even if* you divide through by $\sigma^2$ (which is also very small). So the error clearly decays very fast, and the paper's heuristic is about as justified as a heuristic can be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Some minor corrections: (a) After "we can bound", how did you obtain the last inequality? Note that $M:=\{x\in\mathbb R^2:|x_1|\ge\frac\mu\sigma,|x_2|\ge\frac\nu\sigma\}\subseteq\{x\in\mathbb R^2:|x_i|\ge\frac\kappa\sigma\}=\mathbb R^2\setminus\left(-\frac\kappa\sigma,\frac\kappa\sigma\right)=\left(-\infty,\frac\kappa\sigma\right]^2\cup\left[\frac\kappa\sigma,\infty\right)^2$. This is different from what you've obtained. In particular, where did the factor $4$ came from? (b) Sometimes you've used the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ in your equations; sometimes not.

Comment: @0xbadf00d True, my use of $\lambda$ was inconsistent because I was writing my own stuff whilst also looking at the question statement which used "dx". It's not that different from what I obtained - I just used evenness of the integrand to go from integrating over $M$ to $4\times$ the integral of the positive portion of $M$, which is $(k/\sigma,\infty)^2$

Comment: This is the analogue of something like $\int_{-a}^ax^2\,\mathrm{d}x=2\int_0^ax^2\,\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: Yes, okay. Trivial. In arbitrary dimension, we've got $2^d$ before the integral over $[\frac\kappa\sigma,\infty)^d$.

Comment: Another thing: I guess you should choose $\alpha\le\frac12$. But please tell me: What's the point of considering $\alpha$? I mean, it clearly means that we assume that each coordinate of $z$ is inside $[0,\alpha\sqrt N]\cup[(1-\alpha)\sqrt N,\sqrt N)$. Does it mean that the error increases as we get to the border (i.e. as $\alpha\to0$?)

Comment: @0xbadf00d I mean if you hold $\alpha$ constant then as $\delta\to0^+$ we get really strong error bounds - but if you don’t have any control on $\alpha$, that is, if $z$ can be arbitrarily close to the boundary of $D$, then the error might be quite bad (in particular if $\alpha\approx\delta$ then the error isn’t so small) and when I say ‘bad’ I mean ‘bad’ after you’ve removed the $\sigma^2$ factor (kinda like considering what the percentage error is rather than the absolute error)

Comment: Does the same conclusion hold when $z$ is arbitrary taken from $\mathbb R^2$? $\mu,\nu$ and hence $\kappa$ don't need to be positive then anymore. I at least need this be true for $z=w+h$, where $w\in[0,\sqrt N)$ and $h\in\mathbb Z^2$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I’m not sure. I don’t think the approximation is very good if $z$ is notably outside that region

Comment: Ah, I think we don't need this. Assume $z=w+h$. Then we can simply see that $\frac{\|y-z\|^2}{\sigma^2}=\frac{\|y-w\|^2}{\sigma^2}+\frac{\|y+h\|^2-\|y\|^2-2\langle h,y\rangle}{\sigma^2}$. For the first term, we can apply our approximation in your answer. An the second is easily dealt with, since its integral has an easy analytical form.